# Two java methods with same rest end point

Tags: java

I'm a java developer moving from Java 5 to Java 1.7 and I'm looking at some code not knowing that it was possible.

```
@Path("/myroot")
@Service
public class MyServiceClass {

@POST
@Produces({ "application/x-protobuf" })
@Path("bookid/{bookNumber}")
public Response findBookByBookId(
    @PathParam("bookNumber") String bookNumber, 
    @QueryParam("searchType") String searchType) {
    return ...
}

@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("bookid/{bookNumber}")
public Response findBookByBookIdAsJson(
    @PathParam("bookNumber") String bookNumber, 
    @QueryParam("searchType") String searchType) {
    return ...;
}
```

I've got two methods here with the same rest end point. The only difference is that they produce different resonse types.

My question is if the calling application is calling rootUrl/bookId/1234 it looks like java is smart enough to know what method to call based on the Response type.

Am I right? Could someone please help with my understanding of this.

thanks

Comment: The client making the request should be able to specify the response type it is expecting in the header.  If `application/x-protobuf` is the expected response, then the service might just know which method to invoke.  I am not sure what happens if no expected response is specified in the header (maybe `application/json` becomes the default or something)

Comment: The header to use for specifying in the request what the client is willing to receive is the `accept` header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest endpoint invocation will be determined by `Accept` header

```
 curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://<Server>/bookid/{bookNumber}
```

will invoke

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("bookid/{bookNumber}")
public Response findBookByBookIdAsJson(
    @PathParam("bookNumber") String bookNumber, 
    @QueryParam("searchType") String searchType) {
    return ...;
}
```

And

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/x-protobuf" --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://<Server>/bookid/{bookNumber}
```

will invoke

```
@POST
@Produces({ "application/x-protobuf" })
@Path("bookid/{bookNumber}")
public Response findBookByBookId(
    @PathParam("bookNumber") String bookNumber, 
    @QueryParam("searchType") String searchType) {
    return ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no Java language overriding or overloading going on here. The methods have different names.

Your question has to do with the servlet container routing requests, and it routes requests based on a number of factors. One of those factors can be the value of `@Produces`, which is matched to the media types specified in the remote request's `accept` header.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for that. I realised that and hence changed the title of the post smart quick. But perhaps you answered before you saw the change in the title. Nether the less thank you for the answer. the rest of the answer definitely confirms my suspicion which is the media type determines which method is called.